# How to use Airplay to connect to my Samsung monitor that doesn't support Airplay?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, airplay

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2015.  Its ports are getting a bit flaky (both HDMI and Thunderbolt), but otherwise it works great.

I have a Samsung UHD monitor that is also quite nice (Samsung Business LU28E85KRS/GO, 850 Series).  However, the flaky ports mean the connection to the monitor goes in and out when I move the MacBook Pro.  I can keep it connected, but it's a challenge.

I wonder if I can hook up the MacBook Pro to my monitor using Airplay.  This monitor does not support Airplay, so I'm thinking of an adapter.  However, I wonder if the many airplay adapters for sale have a lag that would make it unpleasant to use like a normal monitor for my MacBook Pro to work.

Whenever I search for this, the Samsung monitors that do support Airplay come up, or people hooking up to a projector, so I'm not able to find useful information.

Thoughts?  Can I use an Airplay adapter or will the lag suck?  Is there something else I can do?